# Stream Analytics to PowerBI of different Account

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I found some tutorials that show a Simple "Device Monitoring" solution using IoTHub -> StreamAnalytics -> PowerBI [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/) and [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/outputting-real-time-stream-analytics-data-to-a-power-bi-dashboard/).

Tried setting up the System as said just use a different Accounts for Azure (private MSDN account) and PowerBI (Work Account), but then i found the following quote.

> Note: Make sure that you are logged into the Azure portal with the same account that you use for Power BI when you click Authorize.

Now I can not use the same Account for both because I do not have an active subscription on my work account. And I can not create a PowerBI account with my gmail address (I got no idea why)

Is there any way I can still get the Stream Analytics connected to my PowerBI Account? And if not is there any alternate Dashboard inside Azure which I can use for a Proof of Concept?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use the same account for Power BI and the Azure portal. You can authorize another (Work account) for Power BI from the Azure portal when you are signed in to your Azure subscription with a Microsoft account.

You might want to take a look at the [Remote Monitoring preconfigured solution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-suite-getstarted-preconfigured-solutions/) as a proof of concept. It deploys a complete end-to-end solution including a custom dashboard and uses IoT Hub and Stream Analytics.